# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigator.push')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to navigate from Homescreen to another screen(Test).I have 'HomeScreen.js' below. Once I click on the register button, I get the above mentioned error.

I've been at this for a whole day, but can't seem to get a straight forward answer.

The error is on my 'Homescreen.js' (Attached screenshot error)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAqDH.png)

Error is pointing to: `this.props.navigator.push` under the `_handleRegisterView` function.

HomeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  AsyncStorage,
  Component,
  TouchableHighlight,
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

import Test from './Test';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'SpeedHack',
  };

  _handleRegisterView = () => {

    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'Test',
      component: Test,
      backButtonTitle: 'Back'
    })
    //alert('Register button Pressed!.');
  }

render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._handleRegisterView}>
          <Text style={[styles.button, styles.blueButton]}>
            Register
          </Text></View>
    );
  }
}
```

Test.js (Doesn't really do anything interesting, loads an image)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let pic = {
      uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg'
    };
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Ssup Dude! Want some bananas?</Text>
        <Image source = {pic} style = {{width: 300, height: 300}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused. In `react-navigation` in order to push a screen, you do not do `this.props.navigator.push`, you use `this.props.navigation.navigate`.

Comment: I'm fairly new to React Native, let me try that out

Comment: @MalcolmMaima An example can be found https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/quick-start